# ad's by google(google adsense) doesn't work properly

Tags: adsense

On some pages they work, but there are pages(with exactly the same content. Just guitar chords & video lessons) they don't. I've even changed the robots.txt, but it didn't help. It doesn't depend on time or page size. I don't even know what it could be. Please give me some advise. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [help] before posting a question. Also `java != javascript` !

Comment: Sometimes my car works, sometimes it doesn't. Please give me the fix.

Comment: ok i wish i could help, but first explan your problem, the way you wrote it is only understood by and only by you..

Comment: Look. But first thanks for respond.
I've added google adsense in December 2016. At first everything was good, but after some time(don't know when it's started)some problems revealed.

Comment: I just add a post with adsense widget and instead of the ad it's just a blank  space. There are some posts I've made like 2 months ago and they don't work yet(I mean the advertisement)
Meanwhile there are posts that I've made 2 weeks ago and they work(ads) So what do I do? It's not about time or some adsense rules. Everything's ok, but there are some issues, that I can't make out why they still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ads doesn't show if the page contains words that are not compatible with AdSense program policies e.g. Adult content, Content that advocates against an individual, group, or organization, Recreational drugs and drug-related content etc.
for more info see this link: [Adsense program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348688?hl=en&ref_topic=1271507&visit_id=1-636251631331038835-3882857243&rd=1)

Comment: there's no inappropriate content on my website. Just guitar chords and video lessons in Armenian. That's all